# Para expertos wordpress

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress-theme

tengo un pequeño problema. Al migrar una web de mi servidor local al remoto, me ha saltado un error y es que me sigue cargando la dirección local antigua, a pesar de que ya he sustituido todos los links en la base de datos por medio del conocido codigo de .... wp_posts set post_content = replace ... y aun sigue apareciendome el dominio local . Aunque la pagina funciona, la información se carga sin problemas, pero los estilos y los archivos javascript siguen con el antiguo dominio local.

¿Que es lo que no he cambiado? he hecho otras migraciones antes y no me habia pasado esto nunca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me aventuro un poco al decirte que puede ser por los link, son "http" y quiza deberian de ser "https" , porque si no me equivoco lo que muestras es el error de consola. Por darte una idea... Sirva decir que no se ni lo que es wordpress

Comment: En estos casos yo lo que hago es lo siguiente: exporto la base de datos en un archivo sql, lo abro en un editor de textos, reemplazo el dominio antiguo por el nuevo en todo el archivo (esto es algo que cualquier editor hace de forma casi automática) y luego lo vuelvo a importar. No es un método muy ortodoxo y hay que hacerlo con cuidado, pero me suele funcionar si el error es por algún campo que se han quedado "colgando" en la base de datos. De todos modos, podrías poner ese conocido código del que hablas para poder analizarlo.

Comment: Hay dos campos en una tabla concreta que son los que afectan de forma global al wordpress, en la base de datos, tabla llamada "wp_options" hay un campo llamado "option_name", busca los registros con valor "siteurl" y "home", cambia su valor al correcto, por ejemplo: http://midominio.com/ ojo! con el http y todo

Comment: ESTE CODIGO LO USO PARA CAMBIAR LOS NOMBRES DE DOMINIOS EN LOS ENLACES DE LA BASE DE DATOS DIRECTAMENTE.update wp_posts set post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://localhost/kbmtrading/', 'http://www.kbmtrading.com');
 update wp_posts set guid = replace(guid, 'http://localhost/kbmtrading/', 'http://www.kbmtrading.com');
 update wp_options set option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://localhost/kbmtrading/', 'http://www.kbmtrading.com');
 update wp_postmeta set meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://localhost/kbmtrading/', 'http://www.kbmtrading.com');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la tabla options (si usas el prefijo por defecto es wp_options) cambia las opciones siteurl y home por el dominio nuevo de tu sitio.

Comment: Hombree!!! Mil gracias, eso era.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta la cláusula `WHERE` en la primera sentencia y te sobran algunos `;`:

```
update wp_posts set 
post_content = replace(post_content,'localhost/kbmtrading/', 'kbmtrading.com') 
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

update wp_posts set 
guid = replace(guid, 'localhost/kbmtrading/', 'kbmtrading.com');

update wp_options set
option_value = replace(option_value, 'localhost/kbmtrading/', 'kbmtrading.com'); 

update wp_postmeta set 
meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'localhost/kbmtrading/', 'kbmtrading.com');
```